# Beats audio 4 speakers + subwoofer not working on DV7 6165us and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

I see a lot of people have issues with beatsaudio on hp laptops, and they solve them  partially/totally editing the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file. However, none of those fixes have worked for me (A guy suggested them to me in the irc chat also).

The problem is that this laptop has two speakers in front, two down the screen and a small subwoofer down the case. The problem is that the two front speakers and the subwoofer don't work at all, thus causing my music and any other sounds bassless (And being a big electronic music fan, I can tell you that's awful).

I dual boot with win8 and I had the same issue there, but quickly fixed it installing the IDT High Definition codec driver from the HP support center, which is seemingly not available for linux at all. The strange thing is that it doesn't seem to be a driver issue, since if I plug some quality headphones, the bass is there, so the audio codec/soundcard is processing all the sound properly, it is just not sending it through the appropiate channels.

In case it is useful, my laptop specs:
http://www.cnet.com/laptops/hp-pavilion-dv7-6165us/4505-3121_7-34800415.html

Comment: Check if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/211201/how-to-activate-subwoofer-in-inspiron-17r

Answer (score 1):

Beats Audio is just a brand name that stands for nothing in particular when talking about laptops and especially Linux. You just happen to have an audio chip that is supported by ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture), but runs an unusual general configuration or speaker configuration.

Have you looked into the sound menu? There should be an option to change the mode, it is probably just set to stereo while higher modes are available. [image]

If that doesn't fix your issue you should run `alsamixer` in terminal and check the options there.

You could also try the newer quantal kernel from the `linux-image-generic-lts-quantal` package that, should come with a newer version of ALSA.