Max volume extremely low
I'm experiencing a problem: the volume is very low, even though it's mechanically at maximum. It worked well on Windows.

Open a terminal, and issue the command: alsamixer
You will get a UI displaying various volume bars.
Press the F6 key. It will bring up a dialogue with the installed sound cards / sound devices. Pick the one you want to adjust. The UI will be updated to reflect the chosen device.
See if any of the volume bars are not on 100%. Navigate with the Left arrow and Right arrow arrow keys, and increase the volume with the Up arrow.
When you are done, press Esc. It will exit the application and you get returned to the terminal.
This was just a guess, maybe your issue is different. But for me this worked on Ubuntu 20.04, on occassion.

Hi, when i write "sudo alsamixer" and entered my password, konsole answer me:
Unable to open mixer: Host is down

That is because you used sudo . The instruction was clear, just use alsamixer in terminal

I opened alsamixer, pressed f6, everything is at max 100% volume but is not real, volume is low, i think because that pc has 4 speaker and in ubuntu for some reason are used just 2
"DTS:X® Ultra
four speakers
HP Audio Boost
Poly Studio"

@Spirit Well, the 4-speaker setup is quite important, that you did not mention in your question. I have found now this: https://askubuntu.com/a/253272. In that version of Ubuntu, the sound settings dialog had offered a choice regarding audio channels layout. If that does not apply to your case, then you can put "4 speakers" or "four speakers" in this site's search bar on the top: there are a few threads (but with some old, outdated, possibly obsolete info). Or you can search the entire web for the term: "4 speakers on Ubuntu".
